# Unable to install RVM system-wide on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby, rvm

I can do a user installation of RVM on Ubuntu 12.04 using the following command:

```
$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

And it works.

However, I would like to do a system-wide install of RVM so it will be installed in /usr/local/rvm. But when I add sudo, the installation just hangs, like so:

```
$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable --ruby
[sudo] password for guarddoggps:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   184  100   184    0     0    475      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   828
100 20511  100 20511    0     0  30262      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 30262
```

So how can I get a system-wide install on Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you can either do the entire command as `root` with

```
sudo -i
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

Or, break the command into two commands -

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io > install.rb
sudo bash -s stable --ruby < install.rb
rm install.rb
```

Comment: So this means every time I want to install a ruby such as 1.9.3, I am going to have to gain root privilege first?

Comment: For a system wide installation? Yes.

Comment: And even to install the passenger gem, I had to use rvmsudo: rvmsudo gem install passenger. I guess I am going to have to use rvmsudo for everything, even though the rvm documentation says you rarely need to use sudo.

Comment: Does rvm expect the system user (e.g. ubuntu user) to be in a group called rvm? The reason why I ask is because when I run capistrano with rvm gem, it keeps prompting for password. I would prefer to add the user in an rvm group so that it wouldn't prompt for password.

Comment: @JohnMerlino And what happens when you add your user to the rvm group?

Answer (score 0):

Per [the documentation](http://rvm.io/rvm/install):

> For a Multi-User install you would execute the following:

```
user$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable
```

There are instructions for using RVM all over the internet, but the only real, truly accurate, source is the RVM site itself. RVM is a fast-moving target and the internet is a vast heap of stale information, so trust the authors for information on how to install it or use it before you trust others.

It's really important to read the entire Installation page.

Comment: I found the page at https://rvm.io/support/troubleshooting good at explaining the usage of sudo/rvmsudo better the main page.